# Gradle delete task dir cannot convert URL to a file

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to delete some files from a folder that's in my server network through sftp.

```
task deleteTask(type: Delete, description: "Deletes the files in sftp://my.server.com") {
    delete fileTree(dir: "sftp://my.server.com")
}
```

And when I run `./gradlew deleteTask` I get:

```
// my.server.com is just an example
> Cannot convert URL "sftp://my.server.com" to a file.
```

Tried looking for it on SO as well as other places but I didn't get anywhere. What's the proper way to point gradle to the server network for deleting files?

Answer (score 0):

I guess using the delte is not the right approach. I would try using ant's FTP task to delete that file:

```
configurations {
   ftpAntTask
}

dependencies {
    ftpAntTask("org.apache.ant:ant-commons-net:1.9.4") {
        module("commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1") {
            dependencies "oro:oro:2.0.8:jar"
        }
    }
}

task ftp << {
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'ftp',
                classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP',
                classpath: configurations.ftpAntTask.asPath)
        ftp(server: "ftp.apache.org", userid: "anonymous", password: "me@myorg.com" action: "delete") {
            fileset(dir: "htdocs/manual")
        }
    }
}
```

This is copied and modified from the gradle docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html